# Unable to create a constant value of type 'EntityType'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, db2

I am using Entity Framework to run the following db2 SQL

```
SELECT CM98.TUCUS01.CUST_NO,   
     CM98.TUMHC08.APPL_DT,   
     CM98.TUUNI30.MDL_ID,   
     CM98.TUMHC08.APPL_ID,   
     CM98.TUMHC08.DLR_NO,   
     CM98.TUMHC07.STAT_CD_DESC_TX,   
     CM98.TUCUS01.LAST_NAME,   
     CM98.TUCUS01.FST_NAME,   
     CM98.TUMHC08.UN_ID,   
     CM98.TUMHC08.PL_ID  
FROM CM98.TUSRV97,   
     CM98.TUMHC06,   
     CM98.TUMHC07,   
     CM98.TUCUS01,   
     CM98.TUUNI30,   
     CM98.TUMHC08  
WHERE ( CM98.TUMHC08.APPL_ID = CM98.TUMHC06.APPL_ID ) and  
     ( CM98.TUMHC07.APPL_STAT_CD = CM98.TUMHC06.APPL_STAT_CD ) and  
     ( CM98.TUUNI30.UN_ID = CM98.TUMHC08.UN_ID ) and  
     ( CM98.TUSRV97.XPROD_DIV_CD = CM98.TUUNI30.XPROD_DIV_CD ) and  
     ( CM98.TUSRV97.XPROD_CD = CM98.TUUNI30.XPROD_CD ) and  
     ( CM98.TUSRV97.MDL_ID = CM98.TUUNI30.MDL_ID ) and  
     ( CM98.TUMHC08.CUST_NO = CM98.TUCUS01.CUST_NO ) and  
( ( "CM98"."TUMHC06"."APPL_STAT_TS" = (SELECT MAX(APPL_STAT_TS) FROM CM98.TUMHC06 WHERE APPL_ID = CM98.TUMHC08.APPL_ID) ) )
```

Below is the Linq query I created,

```
from SRV97 in db.TUSRV97
from MHC06 in db.TUMHC06
from MHC07 in db.TUMHC07
from CUS01 in db.TUCUS01
from UNI30 in db.TUUNI30
from MHC08 in db.TUMHC08
where
 MHC08.APPL_ID == MHC06.APPL_ID &&
 MHC07.APPL_STAT_CD == MHC06.APPL_STAT_CD &&
 UNI30.UN_ID == MHC08.UN_ID &&
 SRV97.XPROD_DIV_CD == UNI30.XPROD_DIV_CD &&
 SRV97.XPROD_CD == UNI30.XPROD_CD &&
 SRV97.MDL_ID == UNI30.MDL_ID &&
 MHC08.CUST_NO == CUS01.CUST_NO &&
 MHC06.APPL_STAT_TS == 
  (from tempTUMHC060 in db.TUMHC06
  where
   tempTUMHC060.APPL_ID == MHC08.APPL_ID
  select new {
   tempTUMHC060.APPL_STAT_TS
  }).Max(p => p.APPL_STAT_TS)
select new {
 CUS01.CUST_NO,
 MHC08.APPL_DT,
 UNI30.MDL_ID,
 MHC08.APPL_ID,
 MHC08.DLR_NO,
 MHC07.STAT_CD_DESC_TX,
 CUS01.LAST_NAME,
 CUS01.FST_NAME,
 MHC08.UN_ID,
 MHC08.PL_ID
}
```

I am getting an error
**Unable to create a constant value of type 'APP.Models.TUCUS01'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context**

I don't know what went wrong..Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Avoid naming your table variables the same as your table types. That'll help. To be more precise: `from srv97 in db.TUSRV97` and so on and so forth. The rest of the code can't tell the difference between your variable and your type since they're named the same.

Comment: Updated the code as per your inputs..Thanks!

Comment: But there's more. It seems that `TUCUS01` can both be the name of a DbSet in the context and an entity name. Maybe there are also navigation properties having this name. This makes code very hard to debug. I would put some effort in meaningful class names (`Customer` in stead of `TUCUS01`) and pluralization (`context.Customers` or `someObject.Customers`). The exception means that you use a Customer object where a primitive value is expected, but I can't see anything suspicious. The only possible cause I can see is that `TUCUS01` in `from CUS01 in TUCUS01` is not a DbSet but a local collection.

Comment: I have updated the code..Is that make the query some what clear? That TUCUS01 is a DbSet..

Comment: There is a problem with my entity data model. I managed to figure it out but getting another problem now. the result of plain SQL and linq doesnt match.Plain SQL statement returns one row but LINQ doesn't return anything

Comment: Please update your question with the new information + model or close this one and ask a new question.